# High CPU usage on JBOSS Server

Tags: soap, jboss, cpu, axis

We have a JBOSS server which has Axis 1.1 deployed on it. We are using JMeter to test performance of the server which uses 300 threads to pump WebService Requests. The Server CPU usage goes upto 60-70% on all 4 CPUs. So we thought, the problem will be in our code, so disabled the whole code, by just returning back from the first function itself. But the CPU usage is still the same after the code modification.

Comment: You really need to state what version of JBoss you're using. There are releases from 4.0 to 7.1 in active use, and the major releases are all very different to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is a garbage collector running too often. Add the following options to your JVM and analyze the results:

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-Xloggc:gc.log
```

You might also consider `-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC` for further details. It will be fairly easy to analyze how much time does the JVM spend inside garbage collector.

If GC is not the problem, you might need to plug-in some profiler to find hot-spots. However the fact that commenting-out the code does not put less stress on the CPU suggest garbage collector.